# ASP.NET MVC - Using IF Statement in my Details View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this in my Details View

```
<tr>
   <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ACTION_STATUS):</td>
   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ACTION_STATUS)</td>
</tr>
```

How do I apply this:

> If ACTION_STATUS == , then display Active Else If ACTION_STATUS ==0, display Inactive, Else Deleted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: To address the edit to the question.

I think the best approach, especially now that there are 3 different status options not just 2 is to do the following (as I recommended in my original answer).

1) Create a dictionary similar to Indrit Kello's answer, but make it "static data" somewhere in your project. Maybe it's loaded from a database table of action statuses. Maybe it is something that you load from a config file, or maybe it's just hard-coded in a static class called "Constants.cs" etc. Depends on the situation. If it were hard coded, you might have a class like:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> ActionStatuses = new Dictionary<int, string>(){
            { 1, "Active" },
            { 0, "Inactive"},
            //etc. Additional statuses go here. No comma on the final entry...
    };
}
```

2) Add a new property to your view model to decode the display text for this status. You can decorate this with attributes etc. as you can normal VM properties so you can continue to use @Html.DisplayFor etc,

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
            // Other properties etc...
            public string ActionStatusDisplayText { get { return Constants.ActionStatuses[this.ACTION_STATUS]}; }
    }
```

3) Use this new property in your view.

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ActionStatusDisplayText)</td>
```

4) If you have to do this lookup in multiple different view models, you might want to consider moving the lookup code into the Constants class so that you can share the same code with multiple places. Especially true if you need to implement hte case where as tatus might not be in the dictionary for some reason (value = -99 for somereason etc.)

Comment: Just seen your edit regarding the deleted status. You can apply that easily enough by extending the answer above. Based on this edit though I'd be very inclined to use method 2.

Additionally, if you are displaying this status in multiple places in your frontend, potentially from differetn view models you might want to centralise the status lookup so that you are not re-writing the code in multiple places.

Comment: The ACTION_STATUS has 3 items (Active, Inactive, Deleted). What you did is for 2 items. How do I apply it for 3 items

Comment: @olugbenga <td>@(model.ACTION_STATUS == 1 ? "Active":(model.ACTION_STATUS == 0 ? "Inactive":"Deleted"))</td>
try this once.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Dictionary instead of if conditions. In this case may seem easy doing an if condition but that is not the right way if there are several branches.

```
Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
data.Add(1, "Active");
data.Add(0, "Inactive");
data.Add(-1, "Deleted");
ViewData["data"]=data;
```

In View you can get them:

```
@{
    var Dictionary = (Dictionary<int, string>)ViewData["data"];
 }
```

and display it as
 `<td>@Dictionary[model.ACTION_STATUS]</td>`

I think this solution is cleaner.

Comment: Please Don't be offended. Where do I create the Dictionary? Is it inside Controller, the View Or where?   'Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
data.Add(1, "Active");
data.Add(0, "Inactive");
data.Add(-1, "Deleted");
ViewData["data"]=data;'

Comment: The top snippet would go in your controller action. It creates the Dictionary and passes into ViewData with key "data". The 2nd snippet goes in your View, somewhere. It retrieves the Dictionary from ViewData and assigns it to a local variable in View scope. The final snippet replaces your existing code.

Comment: If you are going to the effort of creating a Dictionary for this, I'd defiantly split it out somewhere central. See my updated answer where I've expanded on my original advice.

Comment: @olugbenga The first part goes in the action of controller which returns that View("Details");. The second part goes inside view. Please vote this answer if you find it helpful.